# ltng:require not loading scripts in Community pages when LockerService is enabled

Tags: community, lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

Since enabling LockerService our components cannot load external static resource scripts anymore. To test, I created a component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
access="global" >

   <ltng:require scripts="/resource/JQUERY,/resource/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.scriptsLoaded}"/>

</aura:component>
```

...and also the corresponding sciptsLoaded controller function:

```
scriptsLoaded: function(component) {
    console.log("scripts loaded");
}
```

When opening the page the console does **not** output the expected "scripts loaded" text. I also checked the scripts loaded by the page and verfified that "bootstrap.min.js" was not loaded:
[image: Scripts loaded by page]

jQuery was loaded but it might be because it was cached because the afterScriptsLoaded function was not invoked.

<s>I also tried using the same component on a normal lightning app and it works fine (the problem is only in community pages).</s> **EDIT: Turns out LS was disabled for this app. We tried turning on LS on other standalone apps and encountered the same problem (for moment.js / fullcalendar plugin).**

I understand there are some known issues on Locker Service but when can we expect a fix for this? Or in the meantime, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry - I just looked closer at your post - I see that jquery is being loaded so this is not what I thought it was. Looks like your org does not have LS enabled at all (either for Communities or .app's) - I see in the org's audit trail that you deactivated both critical updates. Can you add detailed repro instructions for both the community failure case and the successful standalone .app scenario to your support case asap so I can see this action?

Your are using jQuery v1.12.0 and Bootstrap v3.3.6 (latest) and we are still working through the long list of libraries/frameworks to verify which ones are LockerService compliant (CSP policy forbids use of unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline, and code must comply with ES5 "use strict", cannot manipulate DOM elements that you or the library did not directly create). You indicated that standalone things worked - did you test with Enable Lightning LockerService Security activated for the standalone case?

BTW from cache or not does not matter to ltng:require.

***NOTE: Leaving this for posterity but I do not think its the root cause anymore***

You should be seeing some CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) exceptions in the js console if the problem is what I think it is. Please confirm that you are seeing these exceptions.

The same issue happens with cross namespace /resource references such as when you have a base managed package that a number of other managed packages depends on. Pre Locker Service external script includes were not subject to the stricter CORS standard but now they are.

The good news is that the cross domain issue with $Resource (/resource) has already been fixed in Summer'16 R0 that is scheduled to deploy to production Friday (5/20).

Comment: Wait a tic - the network traffic looks strange to me - what type of Community template is this? Aura appears to be getting loaded more than once and I do not see a request for both /resource for jQUERY and bootstrap.min.js which would account for afterScriptsLoaded being invoked. This also seems that the request for JQUERY is happening before Aura and the app is even initialized/available. This looks less and less like LockerService or Aura issue and something specific to the way Communities integrates LC's into a template.

Comment: ... also the 304 (redirect) on aura_prod.js is a bit of a concern.

Comment: Hi Doug. Thanks for the prompt feedback! We have disabled LS for now as it is blocking our development. We have verified that disabling LS does indeed solve the issues we encountered. I also made a mistake when I tried it on standalone - it turns out that LS was disabled and that's why it worked. For the network traffic I clicked the "name" column and it rearranged the order and so it is not listed according to the loading order. And yes, bootstrap.min.js is not being loaded which is the problem. The Community Template for this is Napili using a custom blank template for the page.

Comment: We also tried enabling LS on other standalone apps and it also caused problems from failing to load moment.js (which is required for fullcallendar jquery plugin). Another thing, I also tried loading only /resource/JQUERY which loads correctly according to network traffic, but afterScriptsLoaded still was not invoked (so I thought it was a cache thing).

Comment: And no, there were no CORS exceptions in the console. By way this is the error for the standalone app with fullcalendar plugin: Uncaught Error: Unable to create locker IIFE: TypeError: Cannot set property 'moment' of undefined throws at xxx://xxxxxxxx/aura_prod.js:1:27

Comment: OK - at least things are not as wacky as they sounded given all of the somewhat conflicting data points I was working with last night. This looks like a run of the mill LS issue after all. We have dozens of fixes on their way out - many of them improve compatibility with libraries such as jQuery. I'll be looking at the specific combination of libraries today. The moment.js issue is interesting. It would be helpful if I could see this in action in your org. I have SU access already from your case but did not have repro instructions and there are alot of components in there to wade through.

Comment: Thanks Doug! We will be sending some repro instructions soon.

Comment: Actually, to reproduce the issue you just need to load these scripts in <ltng:require>: latest bootstrap js, moment.js, fullcalendar.js, scheduler.js (moment, fullcalendar and scheduler must be loaded in that order for the calendar to work [link](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/) ). And then simply turn on LS for community and internal, then try the page and app. LS in our org is currently turned off because we still have development and demos to show.